# A question on limits

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (a^x)/(a^x+1)$$
I want to solve this using only concepts of limits not integration or differentiation, but I am not able to figure out how to start

Comment: What about cancelling out $a^x$ ?

Comment: It's important to know what $a$ is.

Comment: @TedShifrin a>0

Comment: The answers will be different if $a<1$, $a=1$, or $a>1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin So I need to take all the cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $0<a<1$, then as $x \to \infty$,
$$
0<\frac{a^x}{a^x+1}\leq a^x \to 0
$$

If $a>1$, then as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{a^x}{a^x+1}=\frac{1}{1+\frac1{a^x}} \to 1.
$$